# Single file unzip optimization using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, zip, unzip

I have a large zip file that contains 1 file inside.
I want to unzip that file to a given directory for further processing and used this code:

```
def unzip(zipfile: ZipFile, filename: str, dest: str):
    ZipFile.extract(zipfile, filename, dest)
```

This function is called using:

```
 with ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_source:
    unzip(zip_source, zip_source.infolist()[0], extract_path) # extract path is correctly defined earlier in the code
```

It seems like unzipping a large file takes a long time (file size > 500 Mb) and I would like to optimize this solution.

All the optimizations I found were multiprocessing based in order to make the extraction of multiple files faster, however, my zip contains only a single file so multiprocessing doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: Questions that ask for software/library recommendations are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site because any answer is generally just an opinion.

Comment: I am not looking for a library but for an optimization solution (even as pseudo code)

Comment: Do you have control over file creation? Can't you split the file into multiple ones? It would be processing time (if you use multiprocessing supposedly) in detriment of storage, of course. In addition you can outsource the file extraction processes to external programs like 7zip, for example.

Comment: No, it's a file supplied by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parallelize the decompression of a zip file with 1 file inside as long are the file is actually compressed using the usual decompression algorithms LZ77/LZW/LZSS. These algorithm are intrinsically sequential.

Moreover these decompression methods are known to be slow (often much slower than reading the file from a storage device). This is mainly because of the algorithm themselves: their complexity and the fact that most mainstream processors cannot speed the computation up by a large margin.

Thus, *there is no way to decompress the file faster*, although you might find a slightly faster implementation by using another library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was afraid that this is the situation.